# AAD Authentication Without Interactive Login

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory

I have a need to authenticate against Azure Active Directory from a .net Web API. I read Vittorio Bertucci's article: [Using ADAL .NET to Authenticate Users via Username/Password](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/07/08/using-adal-net-to-authenticate-users-via-usernamepassword/), and was wondering if there's any way of getting around the limitation of not being able to do this from a website/confidential client. He describes this as an AAD setting. Is it one that can be turned off?

Any assistance with this would be much appreciated!

Comment: What' wrong with the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not common scenario to use the **Resource Owner Password Credentials** in a web app. The recommend way is that using the **Client Credential flow** as Shawn Tabrizi suggested.

If you do want to use the **Resource Owner Password Credentials flow**, you can construct the request yourself as below:

```
POST: https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/token

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
resource={resource}&client_id={clientId}&grant_type=password&username={userName}&password={password}&scope=openid&client_secret={clientSecret}
```

Comment: Thanks, Fei. This is a really interesting suggestion that I hadn't thought of. I realize this is not a common or even necessarily recommended scenario, but it's important for my purposes. I will give your idea a try and, if it works, mark yours as the answer.

Comment: @tjuni Have you fixed the issue now? Please let me know if you still have the problem.

Comment: Sorry for not replying. I've been going at this problem from various directions. I did try your suggestion and it works beautifully from Fiddler but when I try it in my client (angularjs) app, I get this error:
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxx.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/token. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://my-origin-url' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: I just realized that I can create and post this request successfully from a proxy server-side application (in my case, a .NET web api). I think this is going to be my approach. I will mark your answer as the answer since I am using it, just not on the client side. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Client Credential Flow (App Only Flow) should enable your confidential client to be able to authenticate to a downstream resource without a logged in user. This type of authentication is pure Service to Service Authentication, and will require only a secret for the client app to be presented either in the form of an App Key (symmetric key) or a Certificate Credential (asymmetric key).

However, all forms of access to an AAD Resource will require some form of initial interactive login. In the case of App Only Flows, you will need an Admin to perform an interactive login experience with the Client application, which will then allow subsequent user-less flows.

Check out these sample and let me know if it addresses your question!

https://github.com/azure-samples?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=daemon

I hope this helps!